# Find the last Digit of $237^{1002}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

I looked at alot of examples online and alot of videos on how to find the last digit  But the thing with their videos/examples was that the base wasn't a huge number. What I mean by that is you can actually do the calculations in your head. But let's say we are dealing with a $3$ digit base Number... then how would I find the last digit.

Q: $237^{1002}$

EDIT: UNIVERSITY LEVEL QUESTION.

It would be more appreciated if you can help answer in different ways.

Since the Last digit is 7 -->

- $7^1 = 7$
- $7^2 = 49 = 9$
- $7^3 = 343 = 3$
- $7^4 = 2401 = 1$

  $.......$

  $........$
- $7^9 = 40353607 = 7$
- $7^{10} = 282475249 = 9$

Notice the Pattern of the last digit. $7,9,3,1,7,9,3,1...$The last digit repeats in pattern that is 4 digits long.

- Remainder is 1 --> 7
- Remainder is 2 --> 9
- Remainder is 3 --> 3
- Remainder is 0 --> 1

So, $237/4 = 59$ with the remainder of $1$ which refers to $7$. So the last digit has to be $7$.

Comment: You only have to consider the last number, no matter how big the number is. Follows from binomial throtem

Comment: What's your background? Are you in middle school?  high school? college?  Have you heard of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)?  [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)?  [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem)? This is important for us to know so that we can write an answer that makes sense to you.

Comment: University  Student

Comment: @user372204 what about the other questions?  Have you heard of any of those things?

Comment: The base can be as huge as you like as only the last digit will matter $237^{1002} = {23*10 + 7}^{1002} = $ a bunch of stuff times many powers of 10 $+ 7^{1002}$.  As $7^4 = 49^2 = (50 - 1)^2= $ a bunch of stuff times powers of ten $+ 1$.  The leas digit of $7^4$ is 1.  So the last digit of $7^{4k} = (7^4)^k$ is also $1$.  So the the last digit of $237^{1002} $ is the last digit of $7^{1000 + 2}$ is the last digit of $7^2$ is $9$.

Comment: Note that 7^2 ends in 9. 9^2 ends in 1. So 7^4 ends in 1.  So (7^4)^n ends in 1. Find an n that gets you just about to 1002. And see what power you have left over. Thus, you should be able to do it in your head.

Comment: @fleablood FWIW I think you should make that an answer

Comment: Why are you dividing 237/4.  230 + 7.  230 is a multiple of 10.  So 230 will have *nothing* to do with the last digit.  We could have $473289573892769042859230589027^{1002}$ and *only* the last digit 7 will matter because $473289573892769042859230589020$ is a multiple of 10 and won't effect the last digit.

Comment: You're almost correct, but it should be $1002/4$ which has remainder $2$, so the last digit is $9$.

Comment: Hey OP, @Xammm is right, also if you'd like to know why this pattern arises check my answer below for a solution using [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), which ends up doing exactly this.

Comment: I think that you should have searched the site before asking this question. For all practical purposes this is a duplicate of [this mother thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619), and also more closely contained [in this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498104/11619) and many others.

Comment: Other similar questions: [What will be the units digit of $7777^{8888}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/372518) or [Find the last digit of $77777^{77777}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155705).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The last link you gave was a horrible one to use as a model.

Answer (score 13):

$$
237^{1002} = (23*10 + 7)^{1002} = \sum_{i=0}^{1001}23^{1002-i}10^{1002-i}\;7^i{1002 \choose i} + 7^{1002} =\\ 
[\textit{some huge honking multiple of }10] + 7^{1002} = \\ 
[\textit{some huge honking multiple of } 10] + 49^{501} = \\
[\textit{some huge honking multiple of }10] + (50 - 1)^{501} =\\ 
[\textit{some huge honking multiple of }10] + [\textit{some other gorfurshlugging multiple of }10] + (-1)^{501} =\\
[\textit{some huge honking multiple of }10] + [\textit{some other gorfurshlugging multiple of }10] - 1 = \\
[\textit{some huge honking multiple of }10] + [\textit{one less than some other gorfurshlugging multiple of }10] + 9
$$

So the last digit is $9$.  Thing is only the last digits matter, and the last digits will cycle between $1, 7, 9, 3, 1, 7, 9, 3$.  So you just need the last digit and the remainder of $1002$ divided by $4$.

=====

Crash course in modular arithmetic:

If you have some integer $N$ and we have two integers $a$ and $b$ so that $a = b \pm kN$ for some integer $k$ we say $a \equiv b \mod N$.  We are basically considering an arithmetic system where we consider numbers by how much more than a multiple of $N$ they are.

Ex:  If $4732895738927 \equiv 8647 \mod 10$ because $4732895738927 = 8647 + 10k$.  Basically if $a \equiv b \mod 10$ then $a$ and $b$ have same last digit as $a = b + 10k$ for some $k$.

Lemma:  if $a \equiv b \mod N$ and $c \equiv d \mod N$ then:

i) $a + c \equiv b+d \mod N$

ii) $ac \equiv bd \mod N$

iii) $a^n \equiv b^n \mod N$.

Pf:  i) $a = b + kN$, $c = d + jN$ so $a+c = b + d + (j+k)N$ so $a+c \equiv b+d \mod N$.

ii) $a = b + kN$, $c = d + jN$ so  $ac = (b+kN)(d+jN) = bd + (dk + bj)N + jkN^2 = bd + (dk + bj + jkN)N$.  so $ac \equiv bd \mod N$.

iii) by induction $a^1 \equiv b^1 \mod N$ and if $a^n \equiv b^n \mod N$ then $a^{n+1} = a^na \equiv b^nb \mod N \equiv b^{n+1} \mod N$.

So we can apply this to your problem:  $237 \equiv 7 \mod 10$ so $237^{1002} \equiv 7^{1002}$.

Notice:  If you consider $0, 1,.....,N -1, N, 1 + N, ......, 2N-1, 2N, 2N + 1....$  there are at most $0,1,.....,N-1$ distinct values that can be equivalent $\mod N$ so for all the $a^k$ there must only a finite number of distinct things for $a^k$ to be equivalent $\mod N$ so there must be some $a^k \equiv a^j \mod N$ where $k \ne j$.

And if $a^k \equiv 1 \mod N$ then $a^{nk} = (a^k)^n \equiv 1^n \mod N \equiv 1 \mod N$.

So for example $7^2 \equiv 49 \equiv 9 \mod 10$

$7^3 = 7^2*7 \equiv \mod 10 \equiv 9*7 \equiv 63 \equiv 3 \mod 10$

$7^4 = 7^3*7 \equiv 3*7 \equiv 21 \equiv 1 \mod 10$.

So $7^{1000} = (7^4)^{250} \equiv 1^250 \equiv 1 \mod 10$.

Putting this all together:

$237^{1002} \equiv 7^{1002} = 7^{1000}*7^2 \equiv (7^4)^{250}*49 \equiv 1^{250}*49 \equiv 1*49 \equiv 9 \mod 10$

So $237^{1002}$ and $9$ have the same last digit; $9$.

====

A theorem that is beyond this crash course is *Euler's Thereom*.  If $N$ and $a$ have not common factors, and if $\phi(N) = $ the number of numbers $1,2, ....,N$ that have no common factors with $n$... then $a^{\phi(N)} \equiv 1 \mod N$.

So in your problem $\phi(10) = 4$ because $1,3,7, 9$ have no factors in common with $10$ while $2,4,5,6,8,10$ do.  And $7$ and $10$ have no common factors... So $7^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$.  (And we can test that and $7^4 = 49*49 = 40^2 + 2*9*40 + 9^2 \equiv 81 \equiv 1 \mod 10$.)

So $237^{1002} \equiv 7^{1002} \equiv (7^4)^{250}7^2 \equiv 1^{250}49 \equiv 9 \mod 10$.

Comment: *And the award to most mathematical use of "gorfurshlugging" goes to...*

Answer (score 9):

You want to know the last digit of $237^{1002}$, which is the same as the remainder of $237^{1002}$ after division by $10$. This calls for modular arithmetic. From $237\equiv7\pmod{10}$ it follows that
$$237^{1002}\equiv7^{1002}\pmod{10}.$$
Now the base number is small; can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok so Now..I would just do 7^1..7^2 .... 7^10 and recognize the pattern. Once that happens..i divide the 237 by the pattern number... then look at the remainder and get the answer. Rite???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but it sounds wrong. If you like you can post a more detailed solution, then I can have a proper look.

Comment: 237 = 230 + 7.  The 230 will all be multiples of 10 so they can be ignored.  Only worry about the 7.  The patter of 7 is 1, 49->9, 63->3, 21-1.  It repeats every four.  So the last digit of $237^{1002}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^{1002}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^2$ which is the same as the last digit of $49$ which is the same as $9$.

Comment: I edited...can someone check and tell me if its right

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 5):

$ {\rm mod}\ 10\!:\ \color{#c00}{7^{\large 4}\equiv\bf 1}\,\Rightarrow\, 7^{\large J+4K}\!\equiv 7^{\large J}(\color{#c00}{7^{\large 4}})^{\large K}\!\equiv 7^{\large J}\color{#c00}{\bf 1}^{\large K}\!\equiv 7^{\large J}\, $ by standard [Congruence Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879251/divisibility-for-7/879262#879262).

Finally write $\ 1002 = J\!+\!4K\ $ for $\,0\le J < 4\ $  and apply the above.

Answer (score 2):

We show that the last *two* digits of $237^{1002}$ are $69$.

For any $n \in \mathbb N$, the two digits of $n$ are given by $n\bmod{100}$. If $\gcd(n,100)=1$, $n^{\phi(100)}=n^{40} \equiv 1\pmod{100}$, by Euler's theorem.

Since $\gcd(237,100)=1$, applying Euler's theorem gives

$$ 237^{1002} = \big(237^{40}\big)^{25} \cdot 237^2 \equiv 237^2 \equiv 37^2 \equiv 69\pmod{100}. $$

This proves our claim. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Simple version without the notation:

$7 \times 1 = 7$

$7 \times 7 = 49$

$7 \times 9 = 63$

$7 \times 3 = 21$

Just look at the last digit in each case.

So the last digit of $7^1$ is $7$.  The last digit of $7^2$ is $9$.  The last digit of $7^3$ is $3$.  And, the last digit of $7^4$ is $1$.

Thus the last digit of $7^5$ is also $7$.  And the last digit of $7^9$ is $7$ (because $7^4 \times 7^4 \times 7 = 7^9$, and the last digits thereof are $1 \times 1 \times 7$.)

And the last digit of $7^{51}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^{47}$, which is the same as the last digit of $7^{43}$, which is the same as the last digit of $7^{39}$ (see the pattern?)...which is the same as the last digit of $7^{7}$, which is the same as the last digit of $7^3$, which is $3$.

By the same logic, the last digit of $7^{1002}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^2$, which is $9$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite simple way of solving these kinds of problems using [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).

We want to know $237^{1002}$ mod $10$. As Servaes has pointed out, $237^{1002} \equiv 7^{1002} \mod{10}$, so we can work with $7^{1002}$ which is simpler.

Using Fermat's little theorem (which tells us $7^4 \equiv 1$ (mod $5$)) we get:
 $7^{1002} \equiv (7^4)^{250}\cdot7^2 \equiv 1^{250}\cdot49 \equiv 49 \equiv 4\ \ (\text{mod } 5)$

Also $7^{1002} \equiv 1^{1002} \equiv 1\ \ (\text{mod } 2)$,

The chinese remainder theorem tells us that the system
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 4 \ \ \text{(mod } 5) \\
x \equiv 1 \ \ \text{(mod } 2) \\
\end{cases}

Has exactly one solution mod $10$. It's easy to find it by trial and error since we only have 10 options: the solution is $x \equiv 9$  (mod $10$).

Treating $7^{1002}$ as our unknown and applying that result we conclude $7^{1002} \equiv 9$ (mod $10$).

Edit: a quicker but less *mechanic* way to solve this particular problem is to use Euler's theorem, which is a generalized version of Fermat's little theorem. 
Euler's theorem tells us that if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime then $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$), where [$\phi(n)$ counts the positive integers up to a given integer $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

With $n = 10$ and $a = 7$ we have $7^4 \equiv 1$ (mod 10). (Of course we don't need the theorem to know this, given that $7^4 = 2401$, but that's where we get the idea).

So $7^{1002} \equiv (7^4)^{250} \cdot 7^2 \equiv 1^{250}\cdot49\equiv49\equiv 9 $ (mod 10).

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**:

Modulo $10$, the powers of $237$ up to $1002$, like those of $7$, are $1,7,9,3,1,\cdots 9$. (The period is $4$).

Comment: No thanks to the downvoter who probably missed that the answer is correct and complete.

Comment: Looks like somebody entered here and down-voted several answers (or perhaps one user was down-voted, then down-voted all the others in retaliation).

Comment: @barakmanos: these guys must be missing a "downvote all" button ;-)

Comment: Yes, this is a correct method that I used in junior middle school.  No reason to be down-voted.

Comment: It is quite irritating when no comment is provided, to be honest. Anyway, I have "compensated" you and the other user in this comment-thread, who was also down-voted despite the fact that his/her answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It will be many words to show the related theroy.  So I would like the solve the problem as follow:

1. $237 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$
2. $7 ^ 4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$
3. $1002 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$

Now $237^{1002} \equiv 7^{1002} \equiv 7 ^ 2 \equiv 49 \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$.

So your answer is $9$. In a similar way, you can get the last two digits is $69$ as follow.

1. $237 \equiv 37 \pmod{100}$
2. $37 ^ {20} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$
3. $1002 \equiv 2 \pmod{20}$

Now $237^{1002} \equiv 37^{1002} \equiv 37 ^ 2 \equiv 1369\equiv 69 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: In your first example, how did you guess $4$? In your second example, how did you guess $20$? Did you actually check every $n\in[1,20]$ in order to reach this conclusion? Even so, how do you calculate $37^{20}$? This is not so easy (in opposed to $7^{4}$).

Comment: What I'm trying to imply is that instead of guessing $4$, you could have used $\phi(10)$, and instead of guessing $20$, you could have used $\phi(100)$, which would give you $40$ (instead of $20$) but ultimately lead you to the same result.

Comment: @barakmanos I see what you say. In fact I have said "It will be many words to show the related theroy", and everyone can obtain such complete theroy in any textbooks. I just left this to the questioner and hope he can explore such phenomenons. I think that will be better than showing him/she the truth directly. That's why I gave two examples: for the first one, $4=\varphi(10)$ but for the other one, $20 \ne \varphi(100)$.

Comment: @barakmanos of course, it's worthy to recall that there should be an algorithm to compute $a^b\pmod{n} $ where $0<a,b<n$ and the case that $b<0$. That's another problems. Should I leave a link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation or paste the content of that link? Since there already answers solve this problem in view of different aspects, I don't want to repeat something just in different languages.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I just pointed out some issues, or more precisely, a better way for finding the exponent which yields $1\pmod{N}$. You can feel free to improve your answer regardless of other answers, just as long as it doesn't feel like a complete copy-paste from one of them.

Answer (score 0):

$237^{1002}=237^{1000+2}$

$237^2 \times 237^{1000}$

as you know unit digit in case of powers repeat after each fourth power

so $unit digit(237^2\times 237^{1000})=unit digit(237^2)\times unit digit(237^{1000})$

$=9\times 1=9$

Answer (score 0):

$237\equiv-3\mod10$

$\therefore 237^{1002} \equiv(-3)^{1002} \equiv (-3)^2.(9)^{500}\equiv 9.(-1)^{500}\equiv 9 \mod10$

Answer (score 0):

Finding the last digit of ${237}^{1002}$ is same as finding the last digit of $ 7^{1002}$.

We see that
$7^1 = 7$;
$7^2 = 9$;
$7^3 = 3$;
$7^4 = 1$;
$\dots$

Then comes the repetition of $7$, $9$, $3$ and $1$ as the powers of $7$ increase.

Since our power is even, our choices reduce to last digit of $7^2$ and $7^4$ which are $9$ and $1$ respectively.

Since $1002$ is a multiple of $2$ but not a multiple of $4$,
our choice of power $1002$ of $7$ is same as power $2$ of $7$, which is $9$.

Therefore, $7^{1002} = 9$ (last digit)

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this using Euler's theorem:

- $\gcd(237,10)=1$
- Therefore $237^{\phi(10)}\equiv1\pmod{10}$
- Therefore $237^{\phi(2\cdot5)}\equiv1\pmod{10}$
- Therefore $237^{(2-1)\cdot(5-1)}\equiv1\pmod{10}$
- Therefore $237^{1\cdot4}\equiv1\pmod{10}$
- Therefore $237^{4}\equiv1\pmod{10}$

Therefore
 $237^{1002}\equiv237^{4\cdot250+2}\equiv(\color\red{237^{4}})^{250}\cdot237^{2}\equiv\color\red{1}^{250}\cdot237^{2}\equiv56169\equiv9\pmod{10}$.